# How can I "DRY" up my html and javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dry

I have some html and js codes. I can't understand how can I dry up this codes. I am using bootstrap-3 and jquery-1.11.0. on my js code I have some dropdowns. In dropdown I used a icon. When the dropdowns is collapsed the icon changed to down arrow and when the dropdown is expanded the icon changed to up arrow. I need to dry up the codes of  changing the icons and closing other dropdowns when open one. Is it possible to "DRY" up my html and javascript codes more? If possible, how can I do that? Can anyone help me?

Here is my html codes:

```
    <div id="cpc" class="color-picker-container">
        <div id="cpcc" class="color-picker-container_content">
            <div class="main-tools"><span id="m-tools" class="main-tools-dropdown color-picker uS cursor-pointer">Tools<span id="m-tools-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
            <div class="pred">
                <div class="picker-btn-holder"><span id="tools" class="tools-dropdown color-picker cursor-pointer uS">Predefined<span id="tools-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
                <div class="color-picker-btns-holder">
                    <div class="picker-btn-holder"><span id="btn-color" class="color-dropdown-1 color-picker cursor-pointer">Button color<span id="bg-color-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
                    <ul class="eg-color-ul-1">
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-1" class="eg-color c1"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-2" class="eg-color c2"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-3" class="eg-color c3"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-4" class="eg-color c4"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-5" class="eg-color c5"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-6" class="eg-color c6"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-7" class="eg-color c7"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-8" class="eg-color c8"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-9" class="eg-color c9"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-10" class="eg-color c10"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-11" class="eg-color c11"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-12" class="eg-color c12"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-13" class="eg-color c13"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-14" class="eg-color c14"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-15" class="eg-color c15"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-16" class="eg-color c16"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-17" class="eg-color c17"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-18" class="eg-color c18"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-19" class="eg-color c19"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-20" class="eg-color c20"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-21" class="eg-color c21"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-22" class="eg-color c22"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-23" class="eg-color c23"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-24" class="eg-color c24"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-25" class="eg-color c25"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-26" class="eg-color c26"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-27" class="eg-color c27"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-28" class="eg-color c28"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-29" class="eg-color c29"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-30" class="eg-color c30"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-31" class="eg-color c31"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-32" class="eg-color c32"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-33" class="eg-color c33"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-34" class="eg-color c34"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-35" class="eg-color c35"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-36" class="eg-color c36"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-37" class="eg-color c37"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-38" class="eg-color c38"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-39" class="eg-color c39"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-40" class="eg-color c40"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-41" class="eg-color c41"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-42" class="eg-color c42"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-43" class="eg-color c43"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-44" class="eg-color c44"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-45" class="eg-color c45"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-46" class="eg-color c46"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-47" class="eg-color c47"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-48" class="eg-color c48"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-49" class="eg-color c49"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-50" class="eg-color c50"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-51" class="eg-color c51"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-52" class="eg-color c52"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-53" class="eg-color c53"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-54" class="eg-color c54"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-55" class="eg-color c55"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-56" class="eg-color c56"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-57" class="eg-color c57"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-58" class="eg-color c58"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-59" class="eg-color c59"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-60" class="eg-color c60"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-61" class="eg-color c61"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-62" class="eg-color c62"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-63" class="eg-color c63"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="btn-color-64" class="eg-color c64"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="picker-btn-holder"><span class="color-dropdown-2 color-picker cursor-pointer">Text color<span id="text-color-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
                    <ul class="eg-color-ul-2">
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-1" class="eg-color c1"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-2" class="eg-color c2"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-3" class="eg-color c3"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-4" class="eg-color c4"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-5" class="eg-color c5"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-6" class="eg-color c6"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-7" class="eg-color c7"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-8" class="eg-color c8"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-9" class="eg-color c9"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-10" class="eg-color c10"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-11" class="eg-color c11"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-12" class="eg-color c12"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-13" class="eg-color c13"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-14" class="eg-color c14"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-15" class="eg-color c15"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-16" class="eg-color c16"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-17" class="eg-color c17"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-18" class="eg-color c18"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-19" class="eg-color c19"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-20" class="eg-color c20"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-21" class="eg-color c21"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-22" class="eg-color c22"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-23" class="eg-color c23"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-24" class="eg-color c24"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-25" class="eg-color c25"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-26" class="eg-color c26"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-27" class="eg-color c27"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-28" class="eg-color c28"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-29" class="eg-color c29"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-30" class="eg-color c30"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-31" class="eg-color c31"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-32" class="eg-color c32"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-33" class="eg-color c33"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-34" class="eg-color c34"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-35" class="eg-color c35"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-36" class="eg-color c36"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-37" class="eg-color c37"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-38" class="eg-color c38"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-39" class="eg-color c39"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-40" class="eg-color c40"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-41" class="eg-color c41"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-42" class="eg-color c42"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-43" class="eg-color c43"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-44" class="eg-color c44"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-45" class="eg-color c45"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-46" class="eg-color c46"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-47" class="eg-color c47"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-48" class="eg-color c48"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-49" class="eg-color c49"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-50" class="eg-color c50"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-51" class="eg-color c51"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-52" class="eg-color c52"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-53" class="eg-color c53"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-54" class="eg-color c54"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-55" class="eg-color c55"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-56" class="eg-color c56"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-57" class="eg-color c57"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-58" class="eg-color c58"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-59" class="eg-color c59"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-60" class="eg-color c60"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-61" class="eg-color c61"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-62" class="eg-color c62"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-63" class="eg-color c63"></a></li>
                        <li class="color-holder"><a id="text-color-64" class="eg-color c64"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="picker-btn-holder"><span class="color-dropdown-3 color-picker cursor-pointer">Others<span id="size-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
                    <ul class="eg-color-ul-3 uS">
                        <li class="range-holder">
                            <div class="font-section">
                                <div class="font-size-range-holder">
                                    <a class="range-title uS">Font size:</a>
                                    <div id="size-range" class="flat-slider"></div>
                                    <a class="size-range-value-holder uS">20 px</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="range-holder uS">
                            <div id="padding-h-range">
                                <a class="hp-titel uS">Horizontal Padding:</a>
                                <div id="pt-range" class="flat-slider"></div>
                                <a class="pt-range-value uS">20 px</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="padding-v-range">
                                <a class="Vp-titel uS">Vertical Padding:</a>
                                <div id="ps-range" class="flat-slider"></div>
                                <a class="VP-range-value">20 px</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="range-holder No-B uS">
                            <div id="padding-br-range">
                                <a class="br-titel uS">Border Radius:</a>
                                <div id="br-range" class="flat-slider"></div>
                                <a class="br-range-value uS">0 px</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-tools"><span id="c-tools" class="c-tools-dropdown color-picker cursor-pointer uS">Custom<span id="c-tools-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span></div>
                <div class="custom-tools-holder">
                    <div class="picker-btn-holder"><span id="c-btn-color" class="color-picker cursor-pointer uS">Button color<span id="c-bg-color-arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse-after"></span></span></div>
                    <ul class="c-bg-color">
                        <li class="hsl-holder"><div class="c-color-bg"><div id="range-slider1"></div></div></li>
                        <li class="hsl-holder"><div class="c-color-bg"><div id="range-slider2"></div></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--
        --><div class="puller"><span id="Pico" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my js codes:

```
/* hide the color picker  */
    $(".pred").hide();
    $(".eg-color-ul-1").hide();
    $(".eg-color-ul-2").hide();
    $(".eg-color-ul-3").hide();
    $(".color-picker-btns-holder").hide();
    $(".custom-tools-holder").hide();
    $(".c-bg-color").hide();    
/* toggleClass */

var m_tools_arrow = document.getElementById ('m-tools-arrow');
$(".main-tools-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".pred").slideToggle(300);
    $(m_tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (m_tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(m_tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (m_tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(m_tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(m_tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
var tools_arrow = document.getElementById ('tools-arrow');
$(".tools-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".color-picker-btns-holder").slideToggle(300);
    $(".custom-tools-holder").slideUp (300);
    $(c_tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(c_tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
var c_tools_arrow = document.getElementById ('c-tools-arrow');
$(".c-tools-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".custom-tools-holder").slideToggle(300);
    $(".color-picker-btns-holder").slideUp (300);
    $(tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(c_tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (c_tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(c_tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (c_tools_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(c_tools_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(c_tools_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
var bg_arrow = document.getElementById ('bg-color-arrow');
$(".color-dropdown-1").click(function() {
    $(".eg-color-ul-1").slideToggle(300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-2").slideUp (300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-3").slideUp (300);
    $(text_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(text_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(size_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(size_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (bg_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (bg_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
var text_arrow = document.getElementById ('text-color-arrow');
$(".color-dropdown-2").click(function() {
    $(".eg-color-ul-2").slideToggle(300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-1").slideUp (300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-3").slideUp (300);
    $(bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(size_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(size_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(text_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (text_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(text_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (text_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(text_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(text_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
var size_arrow = document.getElementById ('size-arrow');
$(".color-dropdown-3").click(function() {
    $(".eg-color-ul-3").slideToggle(300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-2").slideUp (300);
    $(".eg-color-ul-1").slideUp (300);
    $(bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(text_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    $(text_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    $(size_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (size_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(size_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (size_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(size_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(size_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});

var c_bg_arrow = document.getElementById ('c-bg-color-arrow');
$("#c-btn-color").click(function() {
    $(".c-bg-color").slideToggle(300);
    $(c_bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    if (c_bg_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down') {
        $(c_bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse');
    }
    else if (c_bg_arrow .className === 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon-expand-collapse'){
        $(c_bg_arrow).removeClass('icon-expand-collapse');
        $(c_bg_arrow).addClass('icon-expand-collapse-after');
    };
});
```

Comment: one tip, make the <li> tags in jquery, and loop though to append them with updated ids/classes using some sort of incrementer

Comment: Posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets think about what we can abstract away, start with anything that is repetitive.

I'll give you a nice hint and you can take it from there:

All the li tags are the same right other than the class and id, so you can create a javascript function that keeps track of a counter, and then use jquery to to append as you loop through:

```
var ol = $('ol');

for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  ol.append('<li id=' + i + '>' + 'hello ' + i + '</li>');
}
```

Working JSBin  https://jsbin.com/paturi/3/edit?html,js,output

On the JS:

The key here is going to be to abstract the css as much as possible:

```
$(".eg-color-ul-1").hide();
$(".eg-color-ul-2").hide();
$(".eg-color-ul-3").hide();
```

what if the class was just `.eg-color-ul`

Then you can hide them all with one line, but it depends on the css without that w cant know if this will work for sure. The point is you need to try and have as few classes / ids as possible. that way you can grab multiple elements and change them al at once.

Comment: Thanks @Omarjmh for your help. I am also looking for my js codes. I need to dry up the codes of  changing the icons and closing other dropdowns when open one.

Comment: come to think of it, I think thats about it for the HTML, the other elements and classes are a little more unique than the li tags, looking at js now, we need to see your css too, can you post it

Comment: just edited the answer, please mark as correct if it helps, thats about all I can do for you

Comment: Thank you very much @Omarjmh for your help.